# How to compile git for solaris under ubuntu? (cross compile git)

Tags: gcc, git, cross-compilation

I'm renting webspace with SSH access and I want to host a git repository on it. I can log in using SSH and put websites up. However, git is not installed on the server. Unfortunately, GCC is also not available on the solaris box, or I couldn't find it.
So, to find a solution, I've tried to compile git myself for solaris (under ubuntu; I dont have solaris) and then upload the compiled git to the webspace to use it there. That's what I'm trying to do, but failed so far because while [building the cross compiler](http://davrux.blogspot.de/2011/06/building-solaris-10-64bit-cross.html), I get the error

```
stdio.h: No such file or directory
```

in step "`make all-target-libgcc`"

which I could not resolve (google didn't help and I dont really know what I'm doing there.)

Can you help me solve this? Or is there any alternative way to get git on this solaris box?

On the solaris box:

```
> uname -a
SunOS gaffer 5.10 Generic_142901-13 i86pc i386 i86pc
```

I've described the same problem on superuser yesterday, but did not get any answers yet:
https://superuser.com/questions/630868/how-to-get-git-on-solaris-webspace

Comment: Comments with raw suggestions are welcome, too.

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct to have git repository on rented space you need to have your provider to support it. In other words - you have to pay for it. Or you need to find free solution or set up your own server. 
I know that because I've seen some providers that charge money for that f.e you can have ssh access but to have git you need to pay more.

Comment: For all others: Even if you think this answer might not be correct, please do NOT downvote this answer, because I specifically asked for comments and suggestions. @piotrektt: I think this is not correct. On my own linux machine, I can create a standard SSH account for a second person. This person could then log in, download the GIT source code, compile it and use it, even if I did not install GIT and he does not have root access. Anyways, please leave this answer here for others to comment.

Comment: I'm sure now that it does work, because there is a tutorial which states that the only requirements are SSH and GCC: http://joemaller.com/908/how-to-install-git-on-a-shared-host/